# How can I solve my flutter app running into race condition issue with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I built a matchmaking flutter app that's suppose to randomly match users for a one-on-one chat. My current issue is that I think that I am running into a race condition during the matchmaking process that sometimes prevent both matched users from entering the same chatroom.  I am currently using flutter to build the app and using Firebase Realtime Database to store the users looking for a match. The matching criteria are based on age, gender, and location preferences. The process: a user enters search mode to look for a match. All users searching are put into a potentialMatches node. A user compares their search criteria with all the potential matches in the database. All the potential matches that meet the search criteria of the user are then added to a list which the user will randomly select another user to to claim as a match by writing its UID into the other users matchUid node. That will trigger the Firebase Realtime Database listener which the other user will now see that it was claimed as a match with the current user. The other user will bypass searching the database to use the current user's UID to enter into the chatroom for the one-on-one conversation. I find that 6/10 times the code executes correctly and the users are placed in the correct chatroom, and the remaining time the claimed user doesn't see that it was claimed by another user. To reiterate, The matchUid node in the Firebase Realtime Database starts as an empty string which then get updated with the UID of the other user that claims the current user as a match. That information is used to determine whether to continue searching for a match or bypass to proceed with accepting a match. Here's a snippet of potentialMatches in the database and my app logic:

[image: potentialMatches in Firebase RTDB]

```
void _activateSearchMode() async {
    //Create reference for potential matches in DB
    DatabaseReference potentialMatchesRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('potentialMatches');

    Stream<DatabaseEvent> potentialMatchesAvailable =
        potentialMatchesRef.onValue;

    potentialMatchesStream =
        potentialMatchesAvailable.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      List<PotentialMatches> potentialMatchesList = [];

      final potentialMatchesMap =
          event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?;

      for (var key in potentialMatchesMap?.keys ?? {}) {
        if (key != currentUserData.currentUser!.uid) {
          potentialMatchesList
              .add(PotentialMatches.fromRTDB(potentialMatchesMap![key]));
        }
      }

      if (_isUserAvailable && potentialMatchesList.isNotEmpty) {
        _findMatch(
            PotentialMatches.fromRTDB(
                potentialMatchesMap![currentUserData.currentUser!.uid]),
            potentialMatchesList,
            potentialMatchesMap);
      }
    });
  }

Future<void> _findMatch(
      final PotentialMatches currentUser,
      final List<PotentialMatches> potentialMatches,
      final potentialMatchesMap) async {
    final isUserClaimed = _checkIfClaimed(currentUser);

    switch (isUserClaimed) {
      case false:
        final matchFound = getRandomUser(currentUser, potentialMatches);

        if (matchFound != null) {
          // update both matched found DB references for both current user and matched user
          _claimMatchedUser(currentUser, matchFound);

          _isUserAvailable = false;

          _printMatchValues(currentUser, matchFound, isUserClaimed);

          await sendFCMNotification(
              'Match Found',
              'Come back to talk to ${currentUser.username}!',
              matchFound.fcmToken);

          _goToMatchFoundScreen(currentUser, matchFound, isUserClaimed);
        }
        break;

      case true:
        final matchFound = PotentialMatches.fromRTDB(
            potentialMatchesMap![currentUser.matchUid]);

        _isUserAvailable = false;

        _printMatchValues(currentUser, matchFound, isUserClaimed);

        await sendFCMNotification(
            'Match Found',
            'Come back to talk to ${currentUser.username}!',
            matchFound.fcmToken);

        _goToMatchFoundScreen(currentUser, matchFound, isUserClaimed);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

bool _checkIfClaimed(final PotentialMatches currentUser) {
    if (currentUser.matchUid == '') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

 Future<void> _claimMatchedUser(final PotentialMatches currentUser,
      final PotentialMatches matchFound) async {
    DatabaseReference matchFoundRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('potentialMatches/${matchFound.uid}');
    DatabaseReference currentUserRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('potentialMatches/${currentUser.uid}');

    await matchFoundRef.update({"matchUid": currentUser.uid});
    await currentUserRef.update({"matchUid": matchFound.uid});
  }

const PotentialMatches({
    required this.genderPreference,
    required this.agePreference,
    required this.matchUid,
    required this.username,
    required this.uid,
    required this.userAge,
    required this.userGender,
    required this.userLocation,
    required this.locationPreference,
    required this.matchDistance,
    required this.fcmToken,
  });

  factory PotentialMatches.fromRTDB(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) {
    return PotentialMatches(
      genderPreference: data['genderPreference'] as String,
      locationPreference: data['locationPreference'] as String,
      agePreference: data['agePreference'] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?,
      matchDistance: data['matchDistance'] as int,
      matchUid: data['matchUid'] as String,
      username: data['username'] as String,
      uid: data['uid'] as String,
      userAge: data['age'] as int,
      userGender: data['gender'] as String,
      userLocation: data['location'] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?,
      fcmToken: data['fcmToken'] as String,
    );
  }

PotentialMatches? getRandomUser(
    PotentialMatches currentUser, List<PotentialMatches> potentialMatches) {
  final matchedUsers = potentialMatches.where((otherUser) {
    final currentUserAgePreference =
        MinMaxAgePreference.fromAgePreference(currentUser.agePreference!);
    final otherUserAgePreference =
        MinMaxAgePreference.fromAgePreference(otherUser.agePreference!);
    final currentUserLocation = LatLng.fromLocation(currentUser.userLocation!);
    final otherUserLocation = LatLng.fromLocation(otherUser.userLocation!);
    final distanceInMiles =
        calculateDistance(currentUserLocation, otherUserLocation);

    debugPrint(
        'Distance between current user and other user: $distanceInMiles miles');

    final currentUserMatchDistance = currentUser.locationPreference == 'nearby'
        ? currentUser.matchDistance
        : double.infinity;

    final otherUserMatchDistance = otherUser.locationPreference == 'nearby'
        ? otherUser.matchDistance
        : double.infinity;

    final effectiveMatchDistance =
        min(currentUserMatchDistance, otherUserMatchDistance);

    final isNearby = (currentUser.locationPreference == 'nearby' ||
            otherUser.locationPreference == 'nearby') &&
        distanceInMiles <= effectiveMatchDistance;

    final isAnywhere = (currentUser.locationPreference == 'anywhere' &&
            otherUser.locationPreference == 'anywhere') ||
        (currentUser.locationPreference == 'anywhere' && isNearby) ||
        (otherUser.locationPreference == 'anywhere' && isNearby);

    return currentUser.uid != otherUser.uid &&
        (currentUser.genderPreference == otherUser.userGender ||
            currentUser.genderPreference == 'Any' ||
            otherUser.userGender == 'Non-Binary') &&
        (currentUser.userGender == otherUser.genderPreference ||
            otherUser.genderPreference == 'Any' ||
            currentUser.userGender == 'Non-Binary') &&
        (currentUserAgePreference.max >= otherUser.userAge &&
            currentUserAgePreference.min <= otherUser.userAge) &&
        (currentUser.userAge <= otherUserAgePreference.max &&
            currentUser.userAge >= otherUserAgePreference.min) &&
        (currentUser.matchUid == '' && otherUser.matchUid == '') &&
        (isNearby || isAnywhere);
  }).toList();

  return matchedUsers.isNotEmpty
      ? matchedUsers[Random().nextInt(matchedUsers.length)]
      : null;
}
```

I have tried various methods to slow down how fast the Firebase RTDB reads changes in the databse with Future.delay, StreamController, StreamTransformer, trottleTime, debounce, Timer, Completer, and even adding another database get() to the _checkIfClaimed logic. I got the same results each time where sometimes the users are in the same chatroom and most of the times they are not in the same room.

Comment: Yo, one thing that could be a problem is if multiple users claim the same person as a match at the same time. This could go down if two users pick each other as a match at the same time or if a few users are hunting for matches at the same time and end up picking the same person. To avoid this, you could think about using transactions in Firebase Realtime Database so that only one user can claim another user as a match at any given time.

Comment: Thanks @DewaPrabawa, will that also solve the race condition I'm encountering?

Comment: it might help avoid the problem of multiple users trying to claim the same user as a match at the same time. 

In this case, you could use a transaction to update the matchUid field for the potential match that has been claimed by the current user. The transaction would first read the current value of the matchUid field, then update it with the current user's UID if it is currently empty (indicating that the potential match has not yet been claimed). If the matchUid field is not empty, the transaction would abort and retry, ensuring that only one user can claim the potential match at a time.

Comment: @DewaPrabawa my real issue is the claimed user not always seeing that there's a UID written to its matchUid node when the listener triggers. I implemented your suggestions about transactions, but I'm still running into the issue of the matched users not getting into the same chat session due to the race condition. Any suggestions on how to ensure the the matched user will get the UID of the user that claimed them every time?